# Redux to replace entire database with node.js?

Tags: node.js, redux

Is it possible to have Redux replace your entire database (think data persistence  reasons we use traditional DB, like mySQL) if running on node.js? How can it be done? Are there any limitiations?

Comment: You could replace your entire database with a text file. You won't do it because it's slow. Same thing here IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux is focused on application and component state, not storing large amounts of data.

> Redux is simply about transforming your local state via actions and reducers.
>
> [-mind juice](https://github.com/rackt/redux/issues/464)

Typically, if you need persistence, then you need a separate database that is wired to Redux. Also note, Redux is tiny and doesn't really help you fetch/bind to remote data:

> [Redux] isn’t a real library like React or Relay. It’s a glorified global
>   state event emitter!
>
> [-dan_abramov](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/678419254937526272)

Comment: Thank you Ashley :) I was wondering because I came across this mind blowing article linked by Dan Abramov's (Redux creator's github page): http://www.confluent.io/blog/turning-the-database-inside-out-with-apache-samza/

Answer (score 1):

You mention persistence - this is something that redux explicitly does *not* do. Redux operates on in-memory data. If nothing else you'd need some sort of database or other storage to hold onto the data across runs. Unless you're fine with all your application state disappearing every time your server restarts.

Comment: Haha... yeah that wouldn't be good.